# DynamoDB GetItem call does not work inside a function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Facing a wired problem in trying to read a dynamo db table in node JS function

```
function handleTestRequestQueen(intent, session, callback) {
    var params = {
        TableName: "mysk",
        Key: {
            "name": {
                "S": "la"
            }
        }
    };

    ddb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        console.log(data);
        callback(session.attributes, buildSpeechletResponseWithoutCard("I am the queen!!", "", ""));

    });
    //  callback(session.attributes, buildSpeechletResponseWithoutCard("I am the queen!!" + result, "", "")); 
}
```

When I remove Key from params code is executing and failing.

When I keep the params as defined above I am getting : Intent is invalid.

I tried to run a Lambda code with just one function and it works

```
 var params = {
    TableName: "mysk",
    Key: {
        "name": {
            "S": "la"
        }
    }
};

ddb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    console.log(data);
    callback(session.attributes, buildSpeechletResponseWithoutCard("I am the queen!!", "", ""));

});
```

Is there a syntactical or logical error in the code ?

Comment: Anything else in the error body? Credentials maybe, or different region?

Comment: I am getting this error in the console :
{
    "errorMessage": "Exception: Invalid intent"
}

Comment: Is the error thrown somewhere else? The code you posted doesn't use the `intent` variable.

Comment: that is the only error i get in my cloudwatch logs

Comment: Is name your partition key? getItem can only find a single item where the query is for the exact partitionkey